# IBM DB2: How to retrieve table name in which the trigger is created in?

Tags: triggers, db2

I am working with IBM DB2 database. I have created a trigger in a table. I need to know, from within the trigger, in what table the trigger resides in. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: ... Generally, triggers are customized for the table they're put on.  What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Depends on the DB2 "flavor". DB2 for i has table and schema system names, and a couple other identifying elements, at the beginning of the trigger buffer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no system variable in DB2 LUW that stores the name of the "currently executing trigger", so am not sure you are going to be able to do this dynamically.
However, if you were to hardcode the trigger name into the trigger

```
Declare trigger_schema varchar(128) default '<PutTriggerSchemaHere>';
Declare trigger_name varchar(128) default '<PutTriggerNameHere>';
```

In the body of the trigger(s);

```
Declare schema_name varchar(128) default NULL;
Declare table_name varchar(128) default NULL;
SELECT TABSCHEMA, TABNAME INTO schema_name, table_name 
FROM SYSCAT.TRIGGERS 
WHERE TRIGSCHEMA=trigger_schema and TRIGNAME=trigger_name
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

Hope this helps.